# Should we install carpet before the baseboard and door casings?

Tags: doors, basement, carpet, baseboard, door-frame

We just had a carpet layer come in for measurements and a quote. We've not put in the baseboard or door casings yet, but the carpet layer has suggested that this will make things easier.

Is this true / good advice? Are there any pitfalls to watch for when we go to install the door casings / baseboard?

Comment: The obvious reason : all the sawdust on the new carpet..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It makes it easier for the carpet installer because they don't have the baseboards in the way when they're nailing in the tack strips next to the wall.

On the other hand, it makes things a little more difficult to install the baseboard later because the carpet and tack strips are in the way when you're trying to nail the baseboard to the sole plate in the wall.  This is **much** more of an issue if you're nailing by hand than if you're using a brad nailer.  (I've done it both ways; use a nailer.)  If you're doing a long wall, it can make lining up the pieces of baseboard a little trickier because the tack strip and carpet can get in the way.

On the whole though, I'd follow his advice and use a nailer to install the trim.

Answer (score 11):

My two cents worth.....  We always install the base trim and door trim first. If you have split jam doors with the casings already attached, you must install them first or you will have a real problem fitting the jams to the floor between rooms.  As mentioned, sometimes the carpet installers can scratch the finish on the baseboards, however it is usually minor and easy to touch up after.  The problem I see with putting the trim on last is that depending on the style and thickness of the carpet and pad, you can have a bit of a ridge over the tack strip. Of course you can nestle the trim down into the carpet, but  some of the bottom square edge of your trim may still show.  It is also much more difficult to maintain a level line and make splices on longer runs.  If the corners are not perfectly aligned, then coping the base won't match properly.  Since the trim should outlast the carpet, anytime you need to re-stretch the carpet or remove it, the trim will have to be removed first as it is impossible to do either with the trim in place. Now that is an absolute nightmare and rarely will you be able to salvage all the trim to re-install.

My advise, install the trim and doors first and stress to the carpet installers to be as careful as possible. You can also put a strip of 2 inch delicate work painter's tape on your trim before the carpet goes down. Leave about a half inch at the bottom of the trim uncovered, then remove it after the carpet is installed.  This will help prevent some of the minor scratches the edge of the carpet can cause before it is chiseled behind the tack strip.

Comment: +1 completely agree on the trim first. We also install our trim 1/2" above the floor using some small wood spacers to save us the measuring. The carpet can then be installed so that any excess goes under the trim.

Comment: Our carpet installer said wanted the baseboards installed first as well.  I did not notice any damage to the baseboards, but it would have been easy enough to touch it up after the fact.

Comment: Good hint on the spacing BMitch.  The carpet guys got you all trained well.  LOL  Does make it a lot easier for them to tuck the edges.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that this would be your advice for "built-in" cabinets, too?

Comment: Absolutely correct Andrew

Answer (score 2):

I worked many years for a new contruction house painting company and the proper way is to install trim before carpeting. It's how the pros do it it.  Amateur house flippers I'm sure won't agree....or the guy you hire to replace your trim that's looking for a fast buck; he'll tell you what he wants you to hear. Beware.

Answer (score 1):

the baseboard goes in first always, the carpet installers don't like this if they have to install new thicker baseboard for the customer, they have to remove the old tack and install new, this is very time consuming and their usually on piece work. In my house they had to go from carpet to tile and lino. Putting base on top of carpet then to tile would not work, plus changing carpet later would mean new baseboard also

Answer (score 0):

If you put the baseboard/casings in first, the carpet has to be fit around them.  And in my experience, the carpet installers will damage the baseboards as they stretch the carpet.

If you wait until the carpet is installed, your baseboards can go in on top of the carpet, which will help keep the carpet in place (not usually a problem but hey...) but at the same time make removing the carpet more difficult (but not much so) in the future.

I cannot say there's a specific *right* way to do it.

Comment: There is no reason they'd damage the trim unless they weren't being careful.  Their tools don't need to touch the trim as they all grip the carpet directly.

Comment: Well there is the carpet edger that needs to cut the carpet as closely to the wall as possible...

Comment: Not wanting to get paint on my new replacement carpet, I painted the baseboards before installation. It would have been nice if the installers or the carpet sellers (Lowes) had suggested I use painters tape to cover the baseboards to avoid the damage they knew would occur during installation. Needless to say I am furious that I need to repaint much of the baseboard in 4 rooms and a stairwell due to the negligence of passing this info on to me from both Lowes and the installers.

Answer (score 0):

It is mandatory in the state of New Hampshire to do it this way (Baseboard Installed First). Rev. NH BC Code 92.18-889.

Comment: That is a really _weird_ thing to have codified. I (rhetorically) wonder what the reason was for writing that into code...